# Show link based on Referrer URL

Tags: php

I am  having a little trouble showing/hiding a link based on the referrer page. I am only worried about the page not any extra querys at the end.

BELOW IS THE UPDATED SCRIPT

```
<? 

$last_page = GetHostByName($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

  if(strpos($last_page,"fall2011"))
    {
        echo '<li><a href="'. $last_page  .'" class="navigation-link">Fall 2011</a></li>';
    }else{
        //THIS IS HERE FOR TESTING
        echo $last_page;
}


?>
```

For some reason I am still not getting the referer data.

Comment: Please turn off register globals. They are deprecated. Use `$_SERVER` instead.

Comment: Don't use `@` and you'll see the error of your ways.

Comment: I updated my script and now I am getting the following error;Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_REFERER in /var/www/vhosts/mypage.com/httpdocs/splash.php on line 4  if there was any kind of url rewrite going on would that mess it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']?

Anyway, you'd want to look into http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php which searches for occurences of a string in another string, rather than testing if two strings match 100%.

EDIT:

Well, when you test the script, do you at least go to the script through a link? You know, you're not a referer otherwise...

If you are going through a link, does the URL where the link is contain fall2011? Also, put an echo 'test'; in the else {} block, see if the condition with strpos() is failing or not.

Comment: I am using both of your recommendations (see edits above) but I am still not getting the URL info.

Comment: I did add an echo test and that worked and yes I am accessing it from a link on the mywebsite.com/fall2011/ page. When I turn on error reporting I get Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_REFERER in /var/www/vhosts/mypage.com/httpdocs/splash.php on line 4

Answer (score 1):

The link most certainly has its protocol, e.g. `http`. You'll need to add it in the strong comparison.

Also

- Access `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`. Register globals is deprecated, and for good reason.
- Don't use error suppressor operator `@`.
- Don't make an `if` with a *do nothing* body and an `else`. Instead, flip the condition.